# WCF : Generics with inheritance and ServiceKnownType

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, inheritance

I am getting the error:

> The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 1392. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Subscriber.Application.DTO.Entities:LastTransaction' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Subscriber.Application.DTO.Entities:CreditCardTransactionDTO'.

I have a PaginatioDTO class that has:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class PaginationDTO<T> : IPagination<T> {

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Data { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Items { get; private set; }
}
```

And I am calling this method in my WCF Service interface

```cs
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesHelper))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISubscriberService : IDisposable {

    [OperationContract]
    PaginationDTO<ChargeDTO> GetMerchantCharges(string merchantId, int page, int size);
}
```

When I update my WCF client, I found out that in the Reference.cs of it has the following line

```cs
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISubscriberService/GetMerchantCharges", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISubscriberService/GetMerchantChargesResponse")]
```

And I figured out that if I add the lines

```cs
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Subscriber.Application.DTO.Entities.CreditCardTransactionDTO))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Subscriber.Application.DTO.Entities.BoletoTransactionDTO))]
```

I am not getting the error any more.

On my class KnownTypesHelper I have:

```cs
    internal static class KnownTypesHelper {

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider) {
        return new List<Type>() {
            typeof(CreditCardTransactionDTO),
            typeof(BoletoTransactionDTO)
        };
    }
```

What I am trying to figure out is how can I, in my KnownTypesHelper declare that my PaginationDTO receives a ChargeDTO as T and inside ChargeDTO I have a prop of type "TransactionDTO" that can be CreditCardTransactionDTO or BoletoTransactionDTO.